# Java works fine in Windows but BlueJ IDE's Java fails

Tags: java, windows

I have the most recent version of Java installed and it works fine in Eclipse and with other programs.

A [Duke University online course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/java-programming-arrays-lists-data/supplement/fxqxm/programming-resources) wants me to download and run [their flavor](http://www.bluej.org/download/files/BlueJ-windows-315-duke.msi) of BlueJ for Windows. I installed it, but it can't launch. It says:

> Could not create the Java virtual machine

After ensuring that the _Java_Options environment variable sets an adequate heap I explored the BlueJ program folder. I see that in bin it has its own javaw.exe. When I try to run this I get the same error.

How can I fix this?

I'm on Windows 10 64-bit.

This IDE claims to have its own JDK and to be ready to run out of the box:

> Windows
>
> On Windows, BlueJ comes bundled with a Java Development Kit, JDK, so
>   only a single download is needed.
>
> ```
> Download the Duke/Coursera specific version (choose Save instead of Run)
> Double-click the downloaded install file and follow the wizard to install it in your preferred location
> By default, the installer will place a shortcut to BlueJ on your desktop
> ```

***Update:***

I finally had the good sense to try run the .exe from the command line and pipe the results to a text file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueJ>BlueJ.exe > tmp.txt
```

The contents of the text file are:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for 2097152KB object heap

So it seems that it doesn't have enough memory, but this is strange because I immediately checked Resource Monitor and my RAM usage is only 2.7 GB out of 16 GB.

To make matters more strange I just changed the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` heap size to 1GB and reran the exact same command. The result was the precise same error message... it's still trying to allocate 2GB even though I scaled back the heap to 1GB...

I also set

> SET JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"

but I still get the same result.

Comment: Just choose another course ;)

Comment: the error just says `Could not create the Java virtual machine` ?? no other details?

Comment: @AntJavaDev Correct

Comment: hmmm this is strange , because generally it displays where was the issue f.e. bad jvm arguments or smth. if you could try 2 things , i) As you are in a windows machine , i suppose you run the IDE as ADMIN, if not please try it cause it might be a permissions issue , ii) is it possible to bind the BlueJ with an already installed java version instead of using the one bundled with ?

Comment: Where did you install it? Try installing it in a folder off your C: drive, such as C:\BlueJ. And check the IDE's settings for where the JDK is located. And see if you can point it at a different JDK. I normally store my JDKs off the root of my C: drive also, in paths with no spaces. Hence, why I don't install path critical software under "Program Files".

Comment: @AntJavaDev That's a good question, I will look into binding it as such. If it would launch I would imagine that would be more straightforward to setup in the settings, but I'll look for a way to do so at install time.

Comment: @ManoDestra It installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. I can't load the IDE to check its settings.

Comment: See if it has a .properties file or .config file in its installation directory? And try installing it in a directory off the C: drive instead.

Comment: @ManoDestra Will do. It's going to be another 6 hours before I'm back at that computer but I will update this on your suggestion tonight.

Comment: @ManoDestra I tried changing the install location but that didn't work. I'm not seeing a config file. Here's what's in the folder: jdk directory, icon directory, lib directory, BlueJ.exe, readme.txt, license.txt, thirdpartylicense.txt

Comment: @ManoDestra I updated the Question just now. It seems that Java / BlueJ claims it can't reserve enough RAM even though the heap is 2GB out of 16GB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At long last I got this working.

The trick was to set the *initial* -- not maximum and not initial and maximum -- heap size in `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to a very **small** value, which I believe is because BlueJ insists on using 32-bit Java even though 64-bit is available:

> SET _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m"

Note that the same setting in `JAVA_OPTS` did no good.

If you have a deeper understanding of why this is and would like to submit a better version of this answer then please do so and I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your firewall setting and if there is any special character used in project name/path then remove it and keep it without special characters.

You may refer the below link may be it will solve your problem,

http://www.bluej.org/faq.html#faq_What_should_I_do_about_this_error___Bluej_was_unable_to_create_a_virtual_machine__VM__to_execute_projects__

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/43029/bluej-not-working/

Comment: Thanks. I have ensured there's no restriction on BlueJ in my firewall. When you're referring to a project, what project are you talking about? I never got the IDE to load, so if you mean a BlueJ project then there is none. That error message is also slightly different from mine. The one you link in the FAQ says *BlueJ* could not create virtual machine and seems to be alluding to a state where the IDE is already launched. Mine does not specify *BlueJ* and the IDE can't launch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall BlueJ.
This time, change the install directory from (C:\Program Files(x86)) to (C:\Program Files).
It should work.